# Diagonally Dominant Tridiagonal Matrix always has an inverse

Tags: matrices, reference-request

We are given the task to go and find a specific theorem from a Mathematics textbook at our university library and look up the proof.

The problem, however, is that I do not know what the theorem is called so I am having some difficulty searching for it in textbooks.

The theorem, in layman's terms, tell us the following:

> A tridiagonal matrix that is diagonally dominant will always have an inverse.

Can anybody please give me a possible reference in which I can go look up this theorem?

Comment: Do you mean a strictly diagonally dominant matrix? The $2 \times 2$ matrix of all ones is  diagonally dominant and tridiagonal but not invertible.

Comment: @copper.hat - yes, my bad :). That is what I ment :)

Comment: See, for instance, "Introduction to Numerical Methods in Differential Equations" by Mark H. Holmes, Theorem 2.1, p. 51 (see https://books.google.de/books?id=Bymo5PKzVJQC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=a+tridiagonal+diagonal+dominant+matrix+is+invertible&source=bl&ots=8CGHY6-zjx&sig=mP19zXUoUYs7cWUBkd9umNu33_k&hl=de&sa=X&ei=-l7nVIC8Jov1UJi1guAM&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=a%20tridiagonal%20diagonal%20dominant%20matrix%20is%20invertible&f=false). Note that you need some additional assumptions!

Comment: Wiki calls it the Levy–Desplanques theorem.

Comment: You should be able to find something in Horn and Johnson's text in chapter 6

Answer (score 0):

a weakly diagonally dominant tridiag matrix is nonsingular, by using LU factorization and induction

Comment: Could you give a sketch of the proof or a link of the demonstration of what you are proposing? I suppose it would be useful for answering the question